# Jump between 2 activities without creating new instanes in Android (start without recreate)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have 2 activities in my app I want to toggle without creating new instance.
This is the flow :
Activity A is created, calls and created Activity B without being finished:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
myIntent.putExtra(Constants.SCORE_EXTRA, score);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

On Activity B I call Activity A again :

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(B.this, A.class);
myIntent.putExtra(Constants.IS_SHOW_GUESS_STATE_EXTRA, true);  
startActivity(myIntent);
```

At this point, since both A and B are set as `android:launchMode="singleTask"` I catch the new launch in `onNewIntent()` of A and `onCreate()` of A is not called. (as I want and expect)

Then I want to call Activity B again :  (I also tried setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` but it didn't work)

```
Intent scoreIntent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(scoreIntent);
```

But this time activity B is re-created and `onCreate()` is called and not 'onNewIntent()`
How can I move back to activity B and not re-create it ?

Thank you

Comment: The Android OS always has the last word if an Activity stays alive or not. I don't know your use case, but I would suggest to create one Activity and have two Fragments in there. This is especially convenient when you need life cycle callbacks. 
Maybe you can tell a bit more about your use case, so we can give some more helpful tips?

Comment: The two activities are totally different, I don't think activity with 2 fragments is the right approach here. The question is why activity B is killed..

Comment: That might be because Android decided the device is low on memory? I don't know :) Since Android can decide to kill an Activity when it is not in the foreground, I'd suggest to save the state of activity B in its onSaveInstanceState() and bring it back to that state when onCreate() with non-empty saveInstanceState OR onRestoreInstanceState() is called.

Comment: Tried it, I keep getting `null` saved-instance

Answer (score 0):

If you are using singleTask

```
android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

then add

```
setIntent(scoreIntent);
```

before calling

```
startActivity(scoreIntent);
```

will do the job as expected.

Have happy coding.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. It still calls onCreate()